# Best method of creating a floating side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP MVC3 website I am working on and would like to create a floating side menu bar that stays stationary in between a set of points. CNNSI.com and speckyboy.com both have similar floating sidebars, albeit for social networking links. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very great-full, especially if you know of an Ajax/javascript method.

Comment: looks like you're on the right path. look at the view-source and reverse engineer it. it's not difficult.

Comment: I noticed a <div> tag called ajax_float but I couldn't find much about his on the internet. There were a few SO discussions about something similar but their links were broken. Looks like it might just be CSS, however if someone knows of a plug-in I would like to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  A very simple way to do it is with CSS, using position:fixed on your element.  Unfortunately, you won't get the smart responsiveness that you're looking for with this method.

If you want to get a little fancier and have it scroll with the user between certain points, you'll need to use a bit of javascript to detect when the user scrolls and where he's scrolled to in the page.  I'm all about the learning experience, but since you're using jQuery, there are  [libraries and plugins](http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/floating-message-plugins/) out there that will make something like this a snap for you.  See the link for more info.